# Fetch a GAE entity from Jinja with a Key

Tags: python, google-app-engine, python-2.7, jinja2

I have made a blog in App Engine, and i'm currently adding commenting support to the blogposts.
I have made a db.ListProperty(db.Key) to store a key for each comment posted to that specific post.

The problem is, i am trying to do this within my template and i cannot use db.get there.

For example, to be able to do something like "Comment.get(key)" from jinja

Do you have any other solutions how to do this within my template, or do i have to move the for function which lists my blogposts away from my template and pass it as a kwarg?

Thanks

Comment: You should definitely be doing it outside of the template. How about adding it to a list, passing it to Jinja and then iterating over it. Or you can make a function extending `BaseModel` like this: `def asDict(self): d={"name" = self.name, "comments"= self.comments} return d`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It took a while and needed some rethinking, but i fixed it.
I moved it away from the template and made a fetch comments function which had the fetched posts as input and outputted a list of comments. Then i just passed this as a kwarg ofc.
It looks like this

```
def get_comments(posts):
    postids = []
    for post in posts:
        postids.append(post.key().id())
    comments = {}
    for i in postids:
        comments[i] = Comment.all().ancestor(Blogpost.get_by_id(i))
    return comments
```

In my jinja template i made a simple for loop that looks like this

```
{% for comment in comments[entry.key().id()] %}
```

Might not have been the best way to do it, but decent and works good